# want to set data form service and assign it to dropdown in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Sorry for silly question but I am new to AngularJS.

- I have a service which will fetch data to HTML page (login.html) in AngularJS.
- I have `login.html` page which will have this data when loading.
- In service I have 3 elements (city names) which will get passed to `login.html`.
- In controller I've assigned the data like `$scope.city=data`.
- I just want to iterate the data so that it will appear in dropdown of city in `login.html`.

Below is my snippet:

```
<div>
    <select ng-model="city" class="dropdown btn btn-sm-3 column col-sm-8 btn-primary dropdown-toggle" required>
        <option>Select City</option>
        <div ng-repeat="n in city"> 
            <option> {{city}}</option>
        </div>              
        </div>
    </select>
</div>
```

Please help me with it.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Share your city object

Comment: public class TestResource{

 @GET
 @Path("/city")
 public Response get(){
  
  List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
  list.add("abc");
  list.add("def");
  list.add("ghi");
  
  return Response.ok().entity(list).build();
  
 }
}

Comment: The object is coming to login.html. But the thing is, it is not showing it elementwise.

Comment: The object coming in response in your ajax call

Comment: you are doing wrong take a look of my posted answer if you would like to use select box

Comment: It worked smoothly. Thanks, The mechanic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to achieve it by the wrong method.

Take a look of this

```
$scope.city = {
    {id: '000001', title: 'Chicago'},
    {id: '000002', title: 'New York'},
    {id: '000003', title: 'Washington'},
}
<div>
    <select ng-model="city" class="dropdown btn btn-sm-3 column col-sm-8 btn-primary dropdown-toggle" required>
        <option>Select City</option>
        <option ng-repeat="n in city"> {{n.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

but from my view you should do like below

```
<select ng-model="city" ng-options="item.id as item.title for item in city"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are getting data in the following form-

```
$scope.Cities = [{
   Name: "Anyname",
   ID: "CityID"
}]
```

Just use this-

```
<select ng-model="city"
        class="form-control" ng-options="city.Name for city in Cities" 
        required>
    </select>
```